# How to get subject details in XACML?

Tags: java, xacml

I have tried following method to get subject section

```
abstractPolicy.getTarget().getSubjectsSection()
```

but from that it dosen't provide any methods to get subject's information. So can I convert it to org.w3c.dom.Node ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sun XACML implementation, although `getMatchList()` method is available in 
`com/sun/xacml/TargetMatch.java` class it isn't available in the `com/sun/xacml/TargetMatchGroup.java` class. So adding following method to the `TargetMatchGroup.java` will solve the problem:

```
public List getMatchList()
{
    return matches;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Subject has one or many SubjectMatches,the subject's information is all in the subjectMatches.